# Can't send e-mail using cpanel and phpmailer

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, cpanel

I'm trying to send e-mails using phpmailer and a cpanel account, the cpanel account says that the door 465 must be used, but it cant connect to send the e-mails , i would like to know what i need to do to send the e-mail , has anyone used cpanel + phpmailer ?, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

phpmailer should work without any issue on any server which supports PHP. You just need to specify correct SMTP server, port, username, password etc. in your script. If you are on shared hosting, you can obtain necessary information from your hosting provider. Generally Port 465 is being used for SMTP over SSL. If your hosting provider has enabled SMTP over SSL, you will need to enable SSL option in your script.

Comment: i'm using the sujested configuration of cpanel

Comment: If it fails to connect that means there some issue with SMTP server.. You should report this to your host.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this settings:

```
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = 'your-account@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'your-password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    $mail->From = 'your-account@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Your name';
    $mail->addAddress('email@domain.com', 'Name');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject test';
    $mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

If you want, it's possible to enable detailed debug:

```
// ...
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
// ...
```